# How do I set up git submodules to get the latest commit from a specific branch without downloading the full history?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Our product has a repo that controls our setup and installation process, and a bunch of others that contain different components. The setup process needs to access certain config files whose master copies are kept in the component repos; currently, those files are duplicated in the install repo, but this means they have to be kept in sync which complicates updates, so I want to move to including the other repos as submodules. The problem is, I want to only download the specific commits that we need - namely the latest commit of a specific branch - without downloading the full history of each repo, and I can't find any set of commands that will do this without giving me `Unable to find current origin/Some_branch revision in submodule path 'REDACTED'` errors.

The specific operations I need to support are:

- After a fresh instance of the installer is cloned, I need to initialize, fetch, and check out all the submodules
- Sometimes new submodules will be added to the installer; after updating an existing instance of the installer by pulling the commit(s) which add them, I need to be able to initialize the new ones *without* affecting any existing submodules

  - Specifically I *do not* want to update the existing repos to the latest commit of the given branch - only initialize the new ones
- Whenever a submodule is initialized, it should check out the latest commit in the branch with the same name as the current branch of the super-project
- Ideally, the required commit should be the only one downloaded, but having to download O(1) additional commits is acceptable
- I need to be able to do this for all submodules at once, without needing a list of what submodules there are (other than `.gitmodules`) or which ones are new. Ideally this should just be a set of global commands in the super-project (e.g. `pull`, `submodule init`, `submodule update`, `submodule foreach`), but a solution that requires parsing the output of `submodule status` using Bash would be acceptable.
- If possible, a solution that is compatible with Git versions at least as old as 2.16.6 would be nice

Comment: I may come back to this question and try to write a real answer, but the current TL;DR situation is: this doesn't work right in old Git versions, and maybe doesn't even work right in current Git versions, there's some ongoing work to make submodules better and making it work right "out of the box" is one of the sub-goals.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but wouldn't marking the submodules as shallow in `.gitmodules` and setting `submodule.name.branch=.` be enough for your purposes?

Comment: @Hasturkin It *should* but it doesn't. If I do that, then `git submodule update` ends up pulling only the HEAD commit from the origin repo instead of pulling the latest commit in the correct branch.